# Will my new company know my official notice period?

Tags: hiring-process, india, notice-period, hiring

I currently hold an offer from an employer. I had told my new employer that my official notice period is 2 months. But my actual notice period is just 30 days so that I can have more time to think and also try for better opportunities in this time. Is it ok? Will this be a problem for me when I join? My company does not mention the resignation date in the release/service letter. Just the releasing date. Is there any other ways my new employer can learn this? Or do they really care? I dont want to be in trouble on my first day. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you located? The only way I could see them finding out is if there's a relieving letter involved.

Comment: I am located in Chennai, India. Yes there is relieving letter provided by my company. But my resignation date will not be mentioned in it.

Comment: Even if it doesn't include the resignation date, if they see that the release date is 1 month after they gave you an offer, that would mean that either your notice period was 30 days or your resigned 1 month before you got an offer.

Comment: If the companies involved have many employees, then HR at the new company might have hired someone from your old company before, and would be wondering why they had 4 weeks notice and you have two months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will they find out? It's possible. If they look at your relieving letter or background check and see that your last day was only a month after your offer and a month before you started, that means that either your notice period was only 30 days or you resigned a month before you got an offer.

Will it affect you? Who knows. In all likelihood, these details will only go to HR, and the hiring manager who negotiated your start date won't see it. Even if they did, they may not notice or care. If I saw that, I would probably make a mental note of the discrepancy but not say anything about it. Other people may be more upset and confront you on it. It all depends on the manager.

Now, you really shouldn't have lied in the first place. You should have just told them you would be available to start work 2 months after you receive your offer - this mentions nothing of the notice period. If you're pressed on it you can always explain that you want to take a month of to travel/visit family/whatever. There's nothing wrong with that, and most employers won't try to get you to start earlier (at least in the US).

Comment: I am not sure "most employers won't try to get you to start earlier" that is true in the US not so in India where employers are notoriously bullies over this sort of thing.  This is one of those things that is likely to bite the OP in the distant future rather than near term though.